# Error when fetching PDB files

Tags: python, biopython

I'm trying to download PDB files using Bio.PDB module (BioPython). The list of accession numbers is coming from a pandas DataFrame. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
def get_pdb(accession, dir='/Users/my_folder'):
    pdb1 = PDBList()
    pdb1.retrieve_pdb_file(accession, pdir=dir)

for i in df.loc[:, 'Structure_(PDB)_id']:
    get_pdb(i)
```

The code was able to download 2 files to my_folder, but after that, this error appeared: `550 Can\'t change directory to pdb1p87.ent.gz: No such file or directory`

Any help or hints of what's going on? It could be an FTP issue?

Comment: careful with the indentation in your code.

Comment: I will edit that, but that's not in my original code. Thanks

Comment: can you post the full error message ?

Answer (score 1):

To fetch my `pdb` files I use the following URL `https://files.rcsb.org/download/1p87.pdb`

My fetch routine looks a little bit like this:

```
import os
import requests as re

def fetchpdb(pdb,dir):
    with open(os.join(dir,str(pdb)+'.pdb'),mode='wb') as f:
        resp = re.get('https://files.rcsb.org/download/'+str(pdb))
        f.write(resp.content)
```

This routine comes with none of the downsides of `ftp` if thats what bio.PDB is using.

If you are allowed to introduce `requests` as dependency I would recommend you this way.

If you have any questions about the code ask away.

Comment: I'm still not familiar with the `os` module. I will give it a try to the idea, but it will take me a couple of days. Thanks!